# Rotation issue of UIAlterView in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8

I am using `UIAlertView` in my application with textField. I launch `UIViewController` in landscape mode and provide only landscape masking. But when I change the device orientation keyboard is autorotate but `UIAlertView` is remains same at the position and hide below the keyboard.

Comment: Your textfield is part of your alert? Or it is like shown by @tapas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. I have used both with & without autoresize, even I use storyboard and xib file in all that cases I got correct result. I am not sure but might be you have done something extra in your code.

Attached is my output and which should also be for you.

[image]     [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check and resign first responder textfield while auto-rotating and make it first responder once orientation is changed.
You can find method in view's lifecycle, which are called while changing orientation, 
`[textfieldName resignFirstResponder];`
And once new orientation is achieved you can again call it this way,
`[textFieldName becomeFirstResponder];`